# views filter problem

Tags: views

Filters on Views only give the possibility for static values. I want to show only nodes with a node ID that is an odd number.

Using PHP code, this is what the filter should do:

```
if ((nid % 2) == 1) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) module would work for this.

Comment: I've just used Views PHP to do arbitrary PHP in the same way I think the OP needs to do here. For reference, I've documented what I did in [an answer to my own question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/25709/3966). I hope someone finds it useful.