# How to use a views contextual filter OR?

Tags: 7, views

After browsing the net and SE for a while it appears to me there is no good solution to combine 2 `contextual filters` with OR (rather than the default AND).

This post mentions a [PHP hack](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25504/complex-view-contextual-filter-with-user-relationships-how-would-i-achieve-thi) and this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/alter-a-views-query-to-use-or-through-the-user-interface) has some links to an [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1451218#comment-6003150) stating a recent change in [views 7.x-3.1](https://www.drupal.org/node/1407192).
It also mentiones using `hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)` to modify the view.

Does anyone have a working example or a better solution?

Comment: I don't think there is a better solution as of now. As said in the threads you pointed, it's an ongoing issue apparently. I stumbled on the same problem this week, and had to find a workaround with attachments. But then, it doesn't give a mixed list but two connected ones, which doesn't fit all needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the patch in this issue : [Pull filter value from an argument](http://drupal.org/node/357082)

It allows you to pass the value from the contextual filter to the "normal filter". There you can do your advanced conditions.

Answer (score 8):

The comment thread starting [here](http://drupal.org/node/1451218#comment-6136692) describes an effective workaround. MotoTribe linked to the same thread, but at the time of his question, there was no working example on that page. Now there is, as follows:

In your module, implement `hook_views_api()`:

```
function MODULENAME_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
  );
}
```

Then add a new file to your module called MODULENAME.views.inc, and implement `hook_views_query_alter()`:

```
function MODULENAME_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'whatever_your_view_is_called') {
    $query->where[0]['type'] = 'OR';
  }
}
```

Also be aware of this caveat:

Apparently, the "Content: Published (Yes)" filter that comes with every View is considered to be a part of the same filter group as the contextual filters (group 0). So in order to make my view display only *published* nodes which belong to any of the groups specified by contextual filters (published AND (arg1 OR arg2 OR ...)), I had to move the "Content: Published (Yes)" into a new filter group (using the "And/Or, Rearrange" dialog). Note that the UI didn't display the "Content: Published (Yes)" filter any differently after I moved it into a new group (there weren't any other groups), but in the query object that gets passed into `hook_views_query_alter()` it did move it from group 0 into group 1, causing the code in the above functions to no longer affect it.

Comment: It is better to at least paraphrase the relevance of the references to the OP's question. Link only answers are discouraged because links may not persist.

Comment: @Triskelion: Ah, you're absolutely right. I've edited my response to fix that.

Answer (score 4):

There is a module which changes handlers of Views to make contextual filters to be used with OR instead of AND:
[Views Contextual Filters OR](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or)

Comment: I want to create a view with content from "current user" + "Content from flagged users (the current user has flagged using follow flag[user])"

Answer (score 2):

The situation with *Contextual Filters* and *Filter Groups* is indeed bleak. Here is thread on D.o about this toppic, which has the same solution as stated by @CoreDumpError.

https://drupal.org/node/1451218

Also, here is a module that can help resolve conflicting contextual and exposed filters...
[Views Filter Harmonizer](https://drupal.org/project/filter_harmonizer)