# Views - get nodes flagged or created by me

Tags: views, flags

I want to list nodes flagged or created by me. You can think this as an "or" filter in views. is there a way to do in in views and flag ?

Answer (score 3):

Views 3 supports groups of filters joined by OR.

1. Edit your View.
2. Under "Filter criteria" click the little down arrow next to "Add" and select "And/or, rearrange".
3. Create a new filter group with the filter(s) you want.
4. Change "operator" to "OR".
5. Save.

If you're using Drupal 6:

> [Views Or](https://drupal.org/project/views_or) allows Views to
>   combine filters or arguments with OR and fields with COALESCE.

Comment: Thanks for reply but it should have act like an argumant. Because ı want to list nodes created by me. How do I do that with filters.

Comment: That is a different question, already asked here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32019/how-to-use-a-views-contextual-filter-or