# Filtering a glossary view

Tags: views

I have a glossary view, which is just the one that comes with Views. I want to allow users to filter the results by taxonomy terms (dropdown) and also by title (search field). The problem I'm running into is that when I click on a glossary letter (e.g. X) then I try to type in a search term that begins with something other than X (e.g. Cat) I get no results. The title search filter is basically just searching within the selected letter in the Glossary. So if I'm on the X page and I search for Cat nothing is found. If I would search for X-ray then that would appear.

Is there any way to make the title filter relatable to the entire view result and not just things that begin with the glossary letter than I have selected?

In the attachment of the view I've tried turning on the "Inherit exposed filters" option but that does not help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by changing your Views filters to be connected using an OR instead of an AND. This option can be accessed by through the Views interface using the steps below.

**1.**

[image]

**2**

[image]

**3**

[image]

Comment: I already have it set to OR :( I think the problem is the contextual filter from the glossary is being applied as AND. I have no idea how to change that though.

Comment: Maybe this module can help, https://drupal.org/project/filter_harmonizer

Comment: Tried that too. It only works if I click a glossary letter first, then search. It doesn't work if I search then click a glossary letter.

Comment: See this related question, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32019/how-to-use-a-views-contextual-filter-or. It looks like you might need to use the patch mentioned there or implement hook_views_query_alter and write PHP code to fix the SQL query.